# How is DOS able to resume after running a real-mode flat memory model program?

Tags: ms-dos

Let's go back to the 70s and 80s.  With a real-mode flat memory model, a program has full control of 64K of memory.  This means that, after DOS launches it, the program can overwrite memory that DOS was in, as well as any other program.

Given that, how was DOS able to "return" after the program exited?

Answer (score 0):

First, the original IBM DOS was released in 1981 with the original IBM 5150 PC, though the CP/M operating system it was based on did exist in the 70's.

I think the best way to describe it is that DOS treats its main memory (the "Transient Program Area" or TPA) as a stack.

Typically the first program loaded is COMMAND.COM and it's at the bottom.  COMMAND.COM can ask DOS to load and give control to another program - the binary is placed into memory where COMMAND.COM ends.  I suppose DOS maintains a "start of free memory" pointer for this purpose.  When the binary executes the DOS call to terminate, DOS decrements back the free memory pointer and the memory is "reclaimed."

Since you only had one program running at once, there wasn't any worry about holes or fragments in this scheme.

DOS did support TSRs, or programs that would terminate and stay resident.  So in this case DOS wouldn't decrement that pointer before returning and the program would remain in memory.  No provision for removing it without special third-party utilities.  TSRs could hook into DOS functions or system interrupts and as such achieve limited multitasking.  The [Wikipedia article on TSRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_stay_resident_program) provides more detailed information.

But yeah, there is no memory protection so any program can really just trash the entire RAM, including where DOS lives, at any time.  In that case executing the DOS return call would crash or behave unpredictably.  This scheme depends on programs cooperating and there is no enforcement.  You could even overwrite DOS entirely, that's what the `LOADLIN` program does - it's a Linux loader for DOS.  I think Netware was the same way, it used DOS to boot but basically the Netware OS replaced DOS in RAM when loading.

Comment: You say "When the binary executes the DOS call to terminate, DOS decrements back ..." -- what does it mean when a binary executes the DOS call to terminate? How is the binary interacting with DOS, if DOS isn't in memory anymore? (Or overwritten?)

Comment: DOS is always in memory.  Completely unprotected of course, so a program can overwrite DOS either by accident or intentionally.  I recall when reviewing DOS API functions that one of them is used to terminate the current program (you don't just RET though you might if it's a COM file and not an EXE).  It will then give control back to the calling program.